# malloc assigned to pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, malloc

I have this problem with C.

I have the following statement.

```
int *a;
a=malloc(100);
```

And I get the following error:

> error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

Any hints on this ?

Comment: This is a legal conversion in C. Are you sure you're not compiling with a C++ compiler?

Comment: I'm pretty confident this is C++ - -fpermissive in particular is a gcc option for C++, not for C.

Comment: It is not clear what the question really is (looking to shut up compiler or fix programming error)? In any case this is too basic to be answered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are compiling your code as C++, in which the code you've used is not valid. For C though, it is valid and you [should not add any cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Note, however, that the argument to `malloc()` is in `char`s, so "100" is a bit random. If you want 100 integers, do:

```
a = malloc(100 * sizeof *a);
```

Comment: You're right, I was compiling as C++. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

When writing C compatible code in C++, where you have to use `malloc` because some pure-C library is going to `free` it, I would recommend writing up a quick typed malloc:

```
template<typename T>
T* typed_malloc( size_t count = 1 ) {
  return reinterpret_cast<T*>( malloc(sizeof(T)*count) );
}
```

which you then use like this:

```
int *a;
a=typed_malloc<int>(100);
```

which creates a buffer sized for 100 `int`s.

Adding in some additional stuff, like guarding against creating classes with non-trivial destructors in this manner (as you expect them to be `free`d without being destroyed), might also be recommended.

Answer (score -4):

`malloc` is returning a void* pointer.

You should do :

```
a=(int*)malloc(100);
```

BTW: This statement is allocating 100Bytes and not 100 ints. 
LE: If you are compiling with gcc, this is not necessary. If you are compiling with g++, this is a must.

Comment: No. you don't need this in C

Comment: a=(int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/50902